# Error when testing whether a matrix is positive semi-definite (PSD) in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am using python 2 and I want to test whether a matrix is positive semi-definite (PSD) or not. 
I have built a random matrix X and I want to test the SDP property of Q = X<sup>T</sup>X.

To do so I have adapted a function that tests positive definite property in order to test positive semi-definite property. Then I compute my matrix Q = X<sup>T</sup>X. X<sup>T</sup>X supposed to be PSD since it is the product of a matrix with its transpose (see [*Is a matrix multiplied with its transpose something special?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special) for more detail on PSD guarantee). However, when I test whether Q is PSD, the function return false.

Does anyone understand where my code is wrong ? Is it my testing function that does not test PSD property or something else?

Here is my script (in a simpler way than it really is):

```
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np

p = 300
N = 100
np.random.seed(18) 
X = bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=p*N).reshape((N, p))
X = 2 * X - 1* np.ones_like(X)
Q = np.dot(X.T, X)
def is_semi_pos_def(x):
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) >= 0)
is_semi_pos_def(Q)
```

And it returns:

```
False
```

Thank you so much for any help on this.

Comment: You don't seem to have accounted for numerical error in the `eigvals` calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the matrix Q you are creating in the script doesn't have full rank if N < p, some of the eigenvals are going to be 0. However as mentioned in the comment , numerical errors in np.eigvals are causing these to become negative:

```
P = 5
N = 3
np.random.seed(18) 
X = bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=N*P).reshape((N, P))
X = 2 * X - 1* np.ones_like(X)
Q = np.dot(X.T, X)
np.linalg.eigvals(Q)
```

returns

```
[1.24244289e+01,  -2.96746135e-16,   2.57557110e+00, 4.23704588e-33,   4.25752762e-18]
```

You can account for the error by just testing whether the eigenvalues are greater than 0 - E for some appropriately small E > 0.  However, if in practice you know that your matrices will be full rank you can calculate the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) which seems to be the fastest method using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

P = 300
N = 100
X = bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=N*P).reshape((N, P))
X = 2 * X - 1* np.ones_like(X)
Q = np.dot(X.T, X)

@timing
def is_semi_pos_def_chol(x):
    try:
        np.linalg.cholesky(x)
        return True
    except np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return False

@timing
def is_semi_pos_def_eigsh(x, epsilon=1e-10):
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvalsh(x) >= -epsilon)

@timing
def is_semi_pos_def_eigs(x, epsilon=1e-10):
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) >= -epsilon)

print is_semi_pos_def(Q)
print is_semi_pos_def_eigs(Q)
print is_semi_pos_def_eigsh(Q)
```

returns:

```
is_semi_pos_def function took 0.001 s
False
is_semi_pos_def_eigs function took 0.073 s
True
is_semi_pos_def_eigsh function took 0.011 s
True
```

We can use the faster `eigvalsh` since the matrix is symmetric. 
Note that the Cholesky decomposition incorrectly returns False because of the non-trivial kernel of Q. But for N=P=300 this isn't a problem:

```
is_semi_pos_def_chol function took 0.002 s
True
is_semi_pos_def_eigs function took 0.118 s
True
is_semi_pos_def_eigsh function took 0.023 s
True
```

If you want an analytically sound answer, you can use sympy to compute the eigenvalues without numerical errors, or compute the Cholesky decomposition using sympy, which also avoids float errors. However the computation times become prohibitive for large N and P:

```
from sympy.mpmath import mp

P = 30
N = 10
X = bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=N*P).reshape((N, P))
X = 2 * X - 1* np.ones_like(X)
M = Matrix(np.dot(X.T, X))
Q = np.dot(X.T, X)


@timing
def is_semi_pos_def_symbolic(x):
    try:
        M.cholesky()
        return True
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
        return False

print is_semi_pos_def_symbolic(M)
print is_semi_pos_def_chol(Q)
print is_semi_pos_def_eigsh(Q)
```

note the significant cost of analytical truth:

```
is_semi_pos_def_symbolic function took 0.908 s
True
is_semi_pos_def_chol function took 0.000 s
False
is_semi_pos_def_eigsh function took 0.000 s
True
```

Comment: Thanks for this well developed answer!